# What name does the auto-generated ivar take when I just declare a property in XCode 4.5 onwards?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5

Earlier I was on XCode 4.2 for a long time on Snow Leopard for a long time.
I have made a straight jump to Mountain Lion with XCode 4.5 on with iOS 6 SDK and ARC.

A lot has changed for me. Just wanted to know, whether the naming style of default variables has changed ?

because in older XCode if I wont declare an ivar myself, it would take the same name as the property.

In 4.5, I declared a property (no synthesize required anymore!).

In the overidden setter, I am trying to use the variable as the same name as the property, say abc.

but XCode is not recognizing it and giving me suggestions of _abc !

Does the auto-generated ivar starts with _ now ?

Comment: Thats bad! breaks backwards compatibility! If I have a  code written in XCode 4.2, then it will not compile here.

although the new one works nicely with auto gen setter template with input parameter name and instance var name separate.
In older XCode, It would create a problem for me.

Comment: and from the answer below its quite clear that what will happen in which case. I take my words back regarding backwards compatibility!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The automatically generated `@synthesize` statement uses instance variables prepended with an underscore:

```
@synthesize abc = _abc;
```

But an explicit `@synthesize` statement without instance variable

```
@synthesize abc;
```

is still equivalent to

```
@synthesize abc = abc;
```

for compatibility with older Xcode versions.