# Is a class property accessible after initialisation and available in a callback method

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

Maybe a complex way of wording it.

The process of what should happen:

1. FirstViewController loads
2. You click a button which presents a new view with the `partial curl`
3. You select a UITableCell
4. You set a property in `FirstViewController` of whatever cell has been clicked on
5. In the callback method in `FirstViewController` you access the property to determine the next phase of execution.

However when setting the property and attempting to retrieve it, it is coming back as being `NULL`. Here is how I am attempting to set it:

`FirstViewController.h`:

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSString *navOption;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *navOption;
```

`FirstViewController.m` ( callback ):

```
@synthesize navOption;

-(void)callBackForNav{
    NSLog(@"Inside callback: %@", navOption);
}
```

Inside the `SecondViewController`:

```
FirstViewController *dw = [[FirstViewController alloc] 
    initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
dw.navOption = @"Filter Results";
```

I would expect in the callback `navOption` to equal Filter Results, however it is outputting as being `NULL`. Any ideas where I have gone wrong?

Comment: It's not a "class property", that is something else. It's just a "property". Also, you should remove the `@synthesize` line of code as that should no-longer be needed. That isn't causing the problem though, I'll post that to an answer.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert ahh sorry, im quite new to this. So you think the problem lies somewhere else?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand this right you have the `FirstViewController` presented then the `SecondViewController` on top of that. The problem I see with the assigning of the `navOption` in your code is that the `SecondViewController` is created a NEW `FirstViewController`, not referencing the old one. So when you pop your stack and go back to the original `FirstViewController` the data wasn't set on it because its a different instance.

Now I see you are trying to do something with class properties, but I'm not sure if this is the right approach and you should focus on getting a reference to the original view controller and set the property there.

If you truly want a class "property" you'll have to do something like this.

```
// MyClass.h
@interface MyClass {
}

+(NSObject*) theObject;

// MyClass.m
+(NSObject*) theObject
{
  static NSObject* staticObject = nil;

  if (staticObject == nil)
  {
    // create object
  }

  return staticObject;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer here! How can I reference the original `FirstViewController`?

Comment: You could create a property on the `SecondViewController` referencing the first, or you could create a protocol/delegate on the `SecondViewController` and have the first implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the @synthesize to

```
@synthesize navOption = navOption;
```

By default @synthensize creates an instance variable with an underscore prefix. So the `navOption` property is not using the `navOption` instance variable. Instead, it is using an instance variable named `_navOption`.

What you should really do is remove the instance variable and @synthesize and always use the property.

FirstViewController.h:

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *navOption;
```

FirstViewController.m ( callback ):

```
-(void)callBackForNav{
    NSLog(@"Inside callback: %@", self.navOption);
}
```

Comment: This should only be done in rare situations where it's actually needed. In this case it isn't needed.

Comment: Your first statements are not correct. `@synthesize navOption;` without an explicit instance variable synthesizes the property as `navOption` *without an underscore*, compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/14556476/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR I don't think so. Haven't checked if there's a special case (there might be...) but I suspect `@synthesize navOption;` is equivalent to `@syntesize navOption = _navOption;`. It does it _with_ an underscore. It may depend what version of Xcode though.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert: Only if you omit the synthesize statement. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/14556476/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR My mistake. "Only if you omit the synthesize statement" is correct.

Comment: *shrug* doesn't really matter, `@synthesize` should not be used at all unless you are using an old version of Xcode or are doing something very unusual.

Comment: I have tested it again and what I said in http://stackoverflow.com/a/14556476/1187415 is still valid. If you *omit* the synthesize statement then the property is synthesized with an underscore. If you write `@synthesize navOption;` without an explicit variable name, then the property is synthesized *without* an underscore (for compatibility reasons).

Answer (score 0):

With this code:

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSString *navOption;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *navOption;
```

You are declaring an Instance Variable "navOption" and a Property "navOption". They are two completely separate variables.

This line of code:

```
dw.navOption = @"Filter Results";
```

Sets the value of the navOption property. The syntax to set an instance variable is `dw->navOption = @"Filter Results"`.

This line of code:

```
NSLog(@"Inside callback: %@", navOption);
```

Is reading the instance variable, which you never set. The code to read a property is `self.navOption` instead of just `navOption`.

The solution is not to use instance variables, as they're not recommended except in situations where you need extreme performance (and in that case, you should be using C anyway instead of Objective-C). Basically instance variables are a language feature that is rarely used in modern programming, but it still exists and they used to be used frequently.

---

Change your NSLog to print `self.navOption` and delete these two lines of code:

```
NSString *navOption; // in the .h file
@synthesize navOption; // in the .m file.
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post this. I have removed the NSString and the @synthesises and changed the NSLog to be `self.navOption` however it is still returning null, im sorry to be such a pain - I am still trying to learn the ropes of Obj-C

Comment: @JoshBoothe There must be a problem elsewhere in your code then. Please update your question with the code you're using after making the changes I suggested.

Comment: I just put an NSLog inside of where I am setting the property I put: `NSLog(@"whats is it: %@", dw.navOption);` which returned the correct value. And interestingly the log from the callback was called BEFORE the log I just showed you. Is this anything to do with the problem?

Comment: Setting the property `self.navOption` sets the corresponding instance variable (`navOption` in this case). Even if it is not recommended, reading the instance variable `navOption` directly would produce the same result as calling `self.navOption` (which reads the same variable via the getter function). *"... reading the instance variable, which you never set ... "* is wrong.